# How To Show User Inputs After Registration Is Completed In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a website. In this website, I have created a Form. In this form, users can type their details and submit. When someone clicks submit button all the data stores into the database. But, Now I want to show User Inputs after registration is completed. I mean, there is page A which users can input and when this user clicks submit button I want to redirect that user to page B and show him, his inputs. I have tried this way, and it gives me this error -

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>       Undefined variable: date (View: D:\wamp64\www\FinalProject\resources\views\addmoney\paywithpaypal.blade.php)

How can I Fix this ??

Form View Page `Book.blade.php`

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form1" method="POST" action="{{ route('booktsinsert') }}"
          enctype="multipart/form-data">

        {{ csrf_field() }}

            <h4><span id="success_message" class="text-success"></span></h4>

        <br>
            <h4 style="font-family: Times New Roman;font-size:200%;color:blue;"> Book {{ $bk->title }} Movie </h4> <br>

            <input type="hidden" name="Movieid" value="{{ $bk->id }}">

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="example-date-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Select Date :</label>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <input class="form-control" type="date" name="date" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy"
                           id="example-date-input">
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

Redirect View page. ( paywithpaypal.blade.php )

```
<h1> {{$date}} </h1>
```

Controller page. ( BookSeatController.php )

```
public function booktsinsert(Request $request)
    {

        $Mid = $request->input('Movieid');
        $date = $request->input('date');
        $st = $request->input('st');
        $sendemail = $request->input('email');

                $user = new BookSeat();
                $user->Movie_id = $Mid;
                $user->sdate = $date;
                $user->stime = $st;
                $user->email = $sendemail;

                $user->save();
            }
            return redirect('paywithpaypal')->with("date", $date);
        }
    }
```

Routes.

```
Route::post('booktsinsert', [
    'uses' => 'BookSeatController@booktsinsert',
    'as' => 'booktsinsert'
]);

Route::get('paywithpaypal', array('as' => 'addmoney.paywithpaypal','uses' => 'AddMoneyController@payWithPaypal',));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
return redirect('paywithpaypal')->with("date", $date);
```

**instead of this**

```
return view('paywithpaypal', ['date' => $date]);
```

I hope this will help...

Comment: Thank U !! It's Working 100% Perfectly !! :D

Answer (score 1):

Data passed using `with` is stored into the session. So to access it, use the following:

```
{{ session('date') }}
```

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use session method to fetch the data. below code redirecting to the dashboard page with staus.

```
return redirect('dashboard')->with('status', 'Profile updated!');
```

Retrieve this status from session method.

```
@if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
@endif
```